# Series outlets with neutrals swapped

Tags: electrical

While doing work on my house I had to remove an outlet. I found that this outlet was run in series, but the neutral was swapped. When I put it back I plan on fixing that - unless there would be some legitimate reason for it? Can anybody explain if there was a reason, or if it was in error. And it seemed to not cause issues, so since it is the neutral it probably didn't matter in the end? This is my crude drawing of how it was set - notice wire 1 and 2 are not lined up.

[image]

Comment: Is the tab connecting the two hot screws intact?

Comment: Good point. If the upper and lower outlets are still linked, the relative position of the two hots vs. two neutrals doesn't matter much (though it's cleaner if they agree)

Comment: The terminology is very unclear. The "load" is whatever might get plugged in to either of the receptacles. And receptacles are NEVER wired "in series". If this is just a duplex receptable with one cable feeding it power, and another continuing on downstream to another outlet, then it makes no difference whatever if the wires from one cable are both connected to the top/bottom screws, or are mixed.

Comment: I hope you're not blindly assuming that "white" is guaranteed to be neutral. Anyways, assuming the tab isn't broken and "Load" means hot (and you verified with a pen tester) then that wiring criss-cross isn't functionally dangerous. It's just confusing for a DIY'er =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *not* what I would call "neutral swapped". Neutral swapped usually, in my limited experience, refers to *hot/neutral swapped*, which is a serious problem. And which I have found in my house, in multiple circuits, and fixed where I found it.

Fortunately, you have a much simpler issue, which is not actually a problem at all.

You do have a terminology issue, which is minimal here but may become important as you do more electrical repairs. The wires providing power (as opposed to neutral) to and from a receptacle are generally referred to as "hot". "Load" is a term used specifically when a wire is *not* coming from the panel but rather carrying "hot" on to other parts of the circuit. So calling both wires "load" doesn't actually make sense. The proper term is to either call them both "hot" or call the one from the panel (bringing hot *to* this location) "line" and calling the one going on to other places "load". Where this matters a **lot** is with GFCI and with smart switches. In those situations it is critical to know which hot wire is supplying power ("line") and which is bringing power (and in the case of GFCI, also for neutral) elsewhere "load".

So change "Load 1" to "Hot 1" and "Load 2" to "Hot 2" and then we continue...

A standard duplex receptacle (*not* GFCI) has two screws on one side for hot and two screws on the other side for neutral. There is a small piece of metal (a removable tab) connecting the screws on each side. With those tabs in place, there is **no difference** between the top and bottom screws on each side. Since there is no difference, it doesn't matter (except to satisfy the OCD of a good electrician) whether you have the hot and neutral wires matched up - i.e., one cable to the top, one cable to the bottom - or not matched up - i.e., one cable with black/hot on top, neutral/white on bottom (on the opposite side, of course) and the other cable black/hot on bottom, neutral/white on top. No difference whatsoever.

There are however some unusual, but 100% legitimate, exceptions. If you have two separate circuits powering this receptacle then:

- The tabs will be removed on both sides.
- The cables must be wired "matched" as you are planning to do.
- If you have GFCI at a previous location in the circuit (obviously you didn't) then the GFCI would trip any time this receptacle was used because of the mismatch.
- You get double power - instead of 15A or 20A for everything together, you get 15A or 20A for the top and the same for the bottom.
- The breakers for the two circuits *must* be either a double-breaker or two breakers next to each other and handle-tied. This is so that a single action will shut off power to both receptacles.
- This configuration (2 cables, 4 wires) would actually only power this duplex receptacle. An additional 2 cables/4 wires would be needed to have the power transfer on to the next duplex receptacle. Which is why I doubt you have this here.

There is a somewhat more common setup called a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC), but that is almost certainly *not* what you have here because the normal setup for an MWBC is separate hots but only one neutral, with the tab removed on the hot side but not on the neutral side.

But I doubt you have any of that. My hunch is "tabs in place, wires flipped, no consequence, flip them to be consistent just because it seems better that way".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had thought load and hot were interchangeable. And I knew the hot/neutral reversed...thus why I tried to word as "swapped" - I couldn't come up with a different term for what I was seeing. Thanks for the great writeup btw.

Answer (score 0):

### Is the tab broken or in tact?

Each side of the receptacle has a terminal with two screws and a tab connecting them.

If the tab at the screw terminal is broken/removed (purposely), then both receptacles are isolated, and they are fed from different sources, e.g. both are on different breakers, or one is switched and the other is not.

Here's a picture of receptacle with removed tab on the live side:

[image]

If the tab is *not* broken, then one pair of wires feeds the receptacle, and the other pair continues the circuit to elsewhere. It then does not matter which of the blacks is wired to which of the live-side screws. Same for neutrals.

This is legal, although the recommended way of wiring is with a pigtail: tie black wires together, and connect to receptacle with one black pigtail, and repeat for white/neutral.

### Tab Removed - isolation

If the tab is removed, it is recommended that each receptacle be wired to a live and its corresponding neutral from the same breaker and same cable (assuming cables, not conduits).

### GFCI

This is mandatory if one or both breakers are of a GFCI type: each GFCI requires the neutral corresponding to the live.

Otherwise, all other neutrals generally land on the same bar inside the distribution centre anyway, so why would in this case pairing still matter?

### EMI

Electrical currents flowing through one cable (a bundle of wires) to the receptacle, and back through a different cable, may cause **Electro Magnetic Interference** (EMI) due to the time varying magnetic field caused by such a loop.

The area ("size") of the loop is determined by the length of cable, usually measured from receptacle to distribution panel / breaker *and* by the distance between the live wire and neutral wire.

If the live wire is not snugly following the corresponding neutral wire, such wires will form a loop antenna emanating interfering electro magnetic waves at 50 or 60Hz. Nearby electronics may be affected by this.

Also, any magnetic coupling can induce currents in adjacent wires or metallic objects and so also for this reason a loop should be avoided. It's likely a lesser problem for the currents at play in home wiring. But in industrial settings this can induce dangerous voltages on nearby metallic objects and it can even heat them, much like in an induction stove.

An easy way to ensure that the loop area is small is to have the wires close to each other and thus in the same cable. Therefore, the receptacle's live and neutral screw terminals should be connected to black and white wires from the same cable (or conduit).